# Using C# Authorize Roles with a Security Group SID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-authorization

I have been using the .NET MVC authorize roles feature. I changed the name of my SG from 'A' to 'B'. Since its been 24 hours and I still don't see the change in name being propagated through the AD servers, I decided to use the SID of the SG instead.

So, I went from this:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = @"domain\SGName")]
```

to this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"S-X-XXXXXX")]
```

1) Will the SID change when the SG name changes?

2) Is the authorization still secured when I use SG SID instead of the name? I gave this a test and I can see that it validates access but since I did not read any documentation about using SID, I wanted to confirm.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778824(v=ws.10).aspx and http://serverfault.com/questions/53717/how-can-i-change-the-sid-of-a-user-account-in-the-active-directory

Comment: None of the links answer my questions. Those just explain how SID works and its nomenclature and the fact that you cannot re-use SIDs.

Comment: It simply indicates SID does not change, if you read the whole thing. So based on that theory it will work.